# Embedding Audio Script Issue

Tags: html

so i'm currently trying to embed some audio into my website using Dreamweaver and for some reason it won't play, is it a problem with the code or just the files? Thanks in advance.

```
<audio controls src="stickerbush.mp3">
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct, I test it, and it work very well. I think you need to check the audio if it is working (or try with another audio) and/or the audio file location